# wordpress footer is not loading after function

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using php code, that i've found to count all images in post in wordpress
But after this code footer and sidebar both not loading. I can't fix it. Here is the whole code of my page. The "counter code" is in the div "photo_gallery_counter" . After it nothing is loaded

```
  <?php 
    /*
    Template Name: Страница фотогалереи
    */ ?>
    <?php get_header();?>



    <div class="center-part" style="max-width: 73%;">
      <div class="padding-side" style="margin: 0 40px;">

        <section class="article">
          <div class="h2" style="margin-top: -14px">
          <h2>Фотоальбомы</h2></div>

          <div class="photo_gallery">

            <div class="photo_gallery_grid">
              <?php if (have_posts()) :
              $args = array(
              'post_type' => 'fotoalbum',
              'publish' => true,

              'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
              );
              query_posts($args);
              while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
              <div class="photo_gallery_album">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="photo_gallery_link">
                  <?php
                  $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large');
                  ?>
                  <div class="photo_gallery_item" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $thumbnail[0]; ?>);">
                    <div class="photo_gallery_item_info">
                      <div class="photo_gallery_title">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                      </div>
                      <div class="photo_gallery_counter">
                        <?php

                        // Get all the attachments
                        // Get all the galleries in the current post
                        $galleries = get_post_galleries( get_the_ID(), false );
                        // Count all the galleries
                        $total_gal = count( $galleries );
                        /**
                        * count all the images
                        * @param array $array The array needed
                        * @return int returns the number of images in the post
                        */
                        function _get_total_images( $array ){
                        $key = 0;
                        $src = 0;
                        while ( $key < count( $array ) ){
                        $src += count( $array[$key]['src'] );
                        $key++;
                        }
                        return intval( $src );
                        }
                        echo _get_total_images( $galleries );
                        ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <?php endwhile;?>
              <?php endif;?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>

      </div><!-- end of gallery-->

      <?php get_sidebar('single'); ?>
      <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Did you check your logs? Probably code from gallery plugin throws any fatal error, which stops parsing of code.

Comment: no, there no errors in the log.

Comment: Which paths with logs have you checked?

Comment: it is not the plugin. There are custom wp gallery on the child page.

Comment: in the browser console

Comment: Check Wordpress log files, Apache/Nginx log files, and PHP log files (if you're running it in CGI mode).

Answer (score 0):

It is a php error which causes the rest of the page not to load for sure. I have noticed an error in your code and that is probably the culprit, but there might be others too. Change

```
$galleries = get_post_galleries( get_the_ID(), false );
```

to

```
$galleries = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false );
```

More on the function here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_gallery
 Let me know if this solved it :)

Comment: sorry, it's not worked. This code is ok, i think, because it's working. The results are displayed on the page.